# How to add new column to order

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I want to know how can I add new column order and make use of it in order details view in order view / my custom tab. I'm running magento 2.4.1 version. Lets call this field **my_custom_field**.

I have add new field tried adding db_schema.xml file with following content:

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
<table name="sales_order" resource="sales" engine="innodb" comment="Sales Order">
    <column xsi:type="varchar" length="255" name="my_custom_field" nullable="true" comment="parcel number"/>

</table>
```

Then I upgraded setup.
Then I tried to set the value of that field for my order in my CustomTab -> execute method:

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order')->getId());
$order->setCustomAttribute('my_custom_field', 'test');
$this->orderRepository->save($order);

var_dump($order->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_field'));exit; # returns null
```

Could anyone point what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way:

```
$order->setMyCustomField('test');
$this->orderRepository->save($order);

var_dump($order->getMyCustomField());exit;
```

If you need to save one or some attribute then try the following way which is faster:

```
$order->setMyCustomField('test');
$this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, ['my_custom_field']);
```

Where **$this->orderResource** is the instance of **Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order**

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly!